# Sequelize - Testing updating a model with virtual fields

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following model:

```js
    const Invoice = sequelize.define("invoice", {
        number: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: { msg: "Invoice number already exists" },
            validate: { ...notEmptyMsg("Invoice number") },
        },
        dateIssued: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: isDateMsg("dateIssued"),
        },
        dueDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                ...isDateMsg("dueDate"),
                isAfterDateIssued(value) {
                    if (this.dateIssued && value < this.dateIssued) {
                        throw new Error("Due date cannot be before the date issued");
                    }
                },
            },
        },
        sender: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: notEmptyMsg("Sender"),
        },
        recipient: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: notEmptyMsg("Recipient"),
        },
        items: {
            type: DataTypes.JSON,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: { isArrayOfItems: validateItemsArray },
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM("Draft", "Issued", "Paid", "Part Paid", "Cancelled", "Disputed", "On Hold"),
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isIn: {
                    args: [["Draft", "Issued", "Paid", "Part Paid", "Cancelled", "Disputed", "On Hold"]],
                    msg: "Invalid status",
                },
            },
        },
        footnotes: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: true,
            validate: {
                isString(value) {
                    if (typeof value !== "string") {
                        throw new Error("Footnotes must be a string");
                    }
                },
            },
        },
        organizationId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: { model: "organizations", key: "id" },
        },
        // Virtual field calculating total
        total: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get() {
                return parseFloat(
                    this.items
                        .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice * (1 + item.taxRate), 0)
                        .toFixed(2)
                );
            },
        },
        // Virtual field calculating subtotal
        subtotal: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get() {
                return this.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice, 0);
            },
        },
    });
```

I am encountering a weird issue with the virtual fields, when updating a field.

The following test passes:

```js
    test("Update an invoice", async () => {
        const invoiceData = createInvoiceData();
        const invoice = await Invoice.create(invoiceData);

        await invoice.update({ recipient: "Lorem" });

        expect(invoice.recipient).toBe("Lorem");
    });
```

But this one throws an error:

```js
    test("Update an invoice", async () => {
        const invoiceData = createInvoiceData();
        const invoice = await Invoice.create(invoiceData);

        await Invoice.update({ recipient: "Lorem" }, { where: { id: invoice.id } });
        const updatedInvoice = await Invoice.findByPk(invoice.id);

        expect(updatedInvoice.recipient).toBe("Lorem");
    });
```

This is the error:

```
  ● Invoice Model › Update an invoice

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

      129 |                 return parseFloat(
      130 |                     this.items
    > 131 |                         .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice * (1 + item.taxRate), 0)
          |                          ^
      132 |                         .toFixed(2)
      133 |                 );
      134 |             },

      at model.reduce (src/models/invoice.js:131:8)
      at model.get (node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:3651:41)
      at model.get (node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:3685:33)
      at Function.update (node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:3247:44)
      at Object.update (tests/invoice.model.test.js:72:17)
```

Apparently, items is "undefined" in this case, when trying to calculate the virtual field "total"

I do not understand why the 2nd way of writing the test fails. I am updating the database, no?

**More strangely even** is the fact that, the same method that fails in the test, seems to work fine in the production code. This is what I do in my express route:

```js
exports.updateInvoice = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const [updateCount] = await Invoice.update(
            { ...req.body },
            {
                where: { id: req.params.id },
            }
        );
```

And it works without problem.

**UPDATE**

Interesting detail I noticed... if what I update in the test case is the `items` field, the test passes...

```js
    test("Update an invoice (Method #1)", async () => {
        const invoiceData = createInvoiceData();
        const invoice = await Invoice.create(invoiceData);
        await Invoice.update({ items: [] }, { where: { id: invoice.id } });
        const updatedInvoice = await Invoice.findByPk(invoice.id);
        expect(updatedInvoice.items.length).toBe(0);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to find a way to solve it. If I declare my model as a "class" instead of using `sequelize.define`, the test passes.

```js
    class Invoice extends Model {
        // Virtual field for calculating total
        get total() {
            return parseFloat(
                this.items
                    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice * (1 + item.taxRate), 0)
                    .toFixed(2)
            );
        }

        // Virtual field for calculating subtotal
        get subtotal() {
            return this.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice, 0);
        }
    }
```

I do not know why the other way does not work, but this is a solution at least.

Answer (score 2):

Consider how Sequelize handles [virtual fields](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#virtual-fields): when you update the invoice using `Invoice.update(...)`, Sequelize does not automatically fetch or include the `items` field in the updated instance. So, when `total` or `subtotal` is accessed, `this.items` is undefined, causing the error.
The fact that it works in production but not in tests might be due to differences in how data is being loaded or accessed in each environment.

It seems unusual for Sequelize to access virtual fields during an update. However, if there are custom hooks or logic in your model that might be triggered during an update, these could inadvertently be causing the error. Check any `beforeUpdate`, `afterUpdate` hooks, or similar custom logic in your model.

As a  defensive programming practice, you could update your model's virtual fields to handle the case where `items` might be undefined: that makes sure virtual fields do not cause errors if dependent fields are not available.

```js
total: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
        return this.items ? parseFloat(
            this.items
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice * (1 + item.taxRate), 0)
                .toFixed(2)
        ) : 0; // Return 0 if items is undefined
    },
},
subtotal: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
        return this.items ? this.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice, 0) : 0; // Return 0 if items is undefined
    },
},
```

If `items` is undefined, the virtual fields return a default value (in this case, 0), which should prevent the error.

Make sure your Sequelize configuration is correct.

Try and add detailed logging around the update operation and in the getters of virtual fields. That can help identify the exact point of failure and the state of the data causing the issue.

---

Regarding your test, instead of trying to include `items` in the update (which is not possible due to the lack of an association), the test could re-fetch the invoice with all necessary fields after updating it.

```js
test("Update an invoice", async () => {
    const invoiceData = createInvoiceData();
    const invoice = await Invoice.create(invoiceData);

    await Invoice.update({ recipient: "Lorem" }, { where: { id: invoice.id } });

    // Fetch the invoice with all necessary fields, including 'items'
    const updatedInvoice = await Invoice.findByPk(invoice.id, {
        attributes: ['id', 'recipient', 'items', /* any other fields needed */]
    });

    expect(updatedInvoice.recipient).toBe("Lorem");
});
```

In the [`findByPk` call](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-finders/#findbypk), you would explicitly specify the attributes to fetch, ensuring `items` is included. That will make sure the virtual fields can compute their values properly.

That assumes that the `items` field is directly a part of the `Invoice` model and not through an association. If `items` is not stored directly within the `Invoice` model but is instead obtained through an association or a more complex query, you would need to adjust the fetch logic accordingly.
And it is also important to make sure the `createInvoiceData` function in your test setup correctly initializes the `items` field.

---

> if what I update in the test case is the `items` field, the test passes...

Your virtual fields `total` and `subtotal` are dependent on the `items` field. When you update the `items` field, Sequelize likely refreshes or reinitializes the instance of the model, including its virtual fields. That refresh makes sure the virtual fields have the necessary data (`items` in this case) to compute their values correctly.

In the failing test case where you were not updating `items`, it is possible that the instance of `Invoice` retained in memory did not have an updated or complete `items` field after the update operation. That could lead to the virtual fields trying to compute their values with incomplete or outdated data, resulting in the error.

Comment: The line of code that throws the exception **is** `Invoice.update`. It is the act of updating the model itself, what causes the failure. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent OK. I have revised the first part of the answer, to add some suggestions. But I kept the defensive programming code.

Comment: I added an update at the end of the question with a curious discovery... Apparently updating "items" does make this work... I wonder why :/

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Good point. I have edited the answer to include some suggestions.

Comment: Even if the instance had not updated the previous value of `items`, it still would be an (empty) array, which means that it wouldn't fail

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent If `items` is always an array (even if empty), the error you encountered (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')`) suggests that during the update operation, `items` may not be in the state you expect. That could happen if Sequelize, for some reason, does not maintain the instance state properly during the update process. Consider testing updates with different fields and combinations of fields. See if updating other fields (especially those not involved in virtual field calculations) also leads to similar issues.

Comment: I ended up posting a solution to my own problem, even though it is still confusing why it happens. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the with following approach.

```
test("Update an invoice", async () => {
    const invoiceData = createInvoiceData();
    const invoice = await Invoice.create(invoiceData);

    await Invoice.update(
        { recipient: "Lorem" },
        { where: { id: invoice.id }, include: [Invoice.associations.items] }
    );
    const updatedInvoice = await Invoice.findByPk(invoice.id);

    expect(updatedInvoice.recipient).toBe("Lorem");
});
```

try it and let me know.

EDIT:
did you try the following to catch ?

```
 get {
    if (!this.items) {
      return 0;
    }

    return 
      this.items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.unitPrice * (1 + item.taxRate), 0).toFixed(2);
  }
```

and please verify the this.item is null or not .

Comment: It doesn't. `Invoice.associations.items` is undefined. (obviously, since I never made any association there)

Comment: The issue is that "items" should **not** be undefined. The invoice data does contain items

Comment: did you try that catch and if not then can you consider it just for one time and verify the `this.items` condition.